# Can I view the HTML source of an email sent to my Gmail address?

Tags: gmail, html

I'd like to see how a certain email was put together.

Is there a "View Source" for emails sent to Gmail?

Comment: Cant you just "view source" in the browser?

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser, but yes, "show original" after clicking on the arrow top-right

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As Jasper pointed out, click the dropdown menu next to the **reply** button, and select **Show original**.

[image: Show original]

Comment: When I do that, I only see the base64 encoding of the source.

Answer (score 21):

Once you get your `Show original` window up, your address bar will contain something like this: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=1234567890&view=om&th=1234abcd1234abcd`

Just change the bit that says `view=om` to `view=lg`.

Push <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and bingo: it’s no longer plain text. Now save it as `.html` or as `.pdf`.

Source: http://blog.brush.co.nz/2012/09/save-a-gmail-message-to-hard-disk/

Comment: If anyone else has the problem where every new line is terminated by an = sign, then this fixes that problem.

Comment: Wow, so hacky. Thanks, it worked!

Comment: Beware: images might be broken! Instead of `https://your-website.com/image.png` they'll be `https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/j78=s0-d-e1-ft#https://your-website.com/image.png`. If your website is intranet-only (i.e. inaccessible from outside your company network / without VPN), you won't see the images since Gmail image proxy servers are unable to reach it. When using desktop email client, images will be shown.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the accepted answer:

If after pressing "View Original" you don't see the HTML code and only see big chunks of random text (Base64) then what you want to do is select the text under the

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

label and copy paste it into a Base64 Decoder (You can find a range of tools that do this online via Google). The results are your HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Select *Print email* and it will open the link in a new window or tab, where you can *right click* see all the source code.

Comment: I think you're thinking of "Show original".

Comment: This is all some odd herd mentality that's downvoting this post. Selecting "print" brings up a considerably less fettered view of the email. From there, view source is much easier to use, as you don't have to contend with all the html from the gmail interface.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks @ki8asui

Answer (score -2):

Don't know the web client of Gmail, but some way to go would be to configure different email client (e.g. Thunderbird with imap a few clicks...) where you can easily view the source of the message.

Comment: Incorrect answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had to actually do show original, and then do view source to see the source HTML.

Comment: Why? Didn't you see the email's source when you did _Show original_?